# Aerater Breaker keeps tripping

Tags: electrical

The aerator for the septic system keeps tripping the breaker.  As far as I can tell that is the only thing on that circuit.  Is this an indication that the motor is going bad?

Comment: Is the motor still spinning with good RPMs when the breaker trips, or is it stalling out?  Can you get us a photo of the aerator motor nameplate for that matter?

Comment: Is it definitely the breaker or is it the a GFCI (Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter)?